# Is there a way to change the relay BandwidthRate and -Burst options during the night?

Tags: relays, bandwidth

I'm operating a tor (guard) relay and I have currently, as per the manual, capped the bandwidth rate and bandwidth burst to allow me to also use my internet connection without any notable performance decrease. This is however not required when I'm asleep or not using the internet connection actively.

Is there a way to allow tor to use more bandwidth during certain hours of the day, and switch to the more strict rate and burst limits during regular hours?

I suppose one solution is to have an automated job deal with modifying the torrc file and restarting tor, but I'm hoping there exists some smart way to achieve the same, other than home-made scripts.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: I don’t think there is, but with a home-made script you wouldn’t need to restart tor, just send a SIGHUP to the process to reload the modified config

Comment: I couldn't find a question asked like this yesterday, but now I found this: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1671/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-tor-relay-use-more-bandwidth-as-certain-times-of-the-da
This question can be closed as a duplicate - I think using the control port is a nice solution.